# countdown function keeps on looping after 12 seconds - please assist

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP page that consists of many data and functions of it, so whenever I click to go to this specific page it loads around 12 seconds. So to notify the user, I have included the below code but it refreshes again and again by decreasing <=0 but the data is already there after 12 seconds completed. Please assist on which line of code I need to change below. Thank you.

```
<p align="center">You will be redirected in <span id='counter'>12</span> second(s).</p>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
    location.href = 'studentPredict.php';
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    }
    setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
    
</script>'";
```

Comment: I don't understand. The code counts down and redirects to that link, but I don't understand what the problem is (what isn't working)?

Comment: Hi @Qirel - My apologize to confused you with my statement. The data display after the 12 second count but then the countdown count again and the data in page gone...then again 12 second and display back. It  is keep on looping after 12 seconds

Comment: so you redirect the user to the same page as where your counter is?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: But why do you whant them to wait 12 seconds and dont show them all data directly?

Comment: Because originally the data in the page took 12 seconds to display all the data. So I added the counter to notify user that they are required to wait for 12 seconds

Comment: @RajeswariRajoo If the counter is on the same page, it will run the counter each time the page is loaded.  Is the same page making an API request (or similar) that is taking up to 12 seconds?

Comment: Of course, it will not do anything special after the redirect if thats redirecting to itself. You haven't told it to do anything on that load.

Comment: Ok, is your server that slow then?

Comment: I think you can better load the content with an ajax call then, display a message while the ajax call is loading the content

Comment: Only that specific page load for 12 seconds, other page working fine. Now the project in localhost, I worried if online it will load more than this

Comment: and if the data doesnt change alot, cache it. so the next load will be much faster

Comment: I dont know about server companies in your country, but in the netherlands they are faster then my local project on my pc

Comment: Noted @Baracuda078 may I know the ajax call that you meant term name? So that I can search by that keyword.

Comment: I posted the link about ajax in my answer

Comment: In order to be more readable, please indent with two spaces only.  Also, anything within a block `{...}` - indent.  Also, what's the `'"` after `</script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments.
I think you can better load the content with an ajax call instead of a redirect. And show the user a message that the content is loading if you whant you can add a timmer to it so the visitor know how long it will probelly take.
More info about ajax: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

If the data doent change that much, cache the data for a specific time so the next request will load much faster. You can cache it in a file or in your system ram with apcu, redis, memcache... Some server dont allow ram cache you need an external server(wich i don't recommend) or cache it in files